# parsed the url and replace the protocol and port number in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am try to write the function in c++ to parse the URL and get the port number and protocol from the url and replaced with different port number and protocol.

For. eg.
Original URL

```
https://abc.com:8140/abc/bcd
```

I need to replaced the https with http and port number as 6143. And merged the URL path like

```
http://abc.com:6143/abc/bcd
```

I am using OS as windows 7 and Visulad studio 6.0.

Thanks,

Comment: We'd be much more inclined to help you sort out any problems if you show us what you've attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution with MFC:

```
static TCHAR strhttp[] = L"http:" ;
void Replace(CString & oldurl, CString & newurl, LPTSTR newport)
{
  int colonposition ;

  colonposition = oldurl.Find(':') ;

  if (colonposition != -1)
  {
    newurl = (CString)strhttp + oldurl.Mid(colonposition + 1) ;

    colonposition = newurl.Find(':', _tcslen(strhttp) + 1) ;

    if (colonposition != -1)
    {
      int slashposition = newurl.Find('/', colonposition) ;
      newurl = newurl.Left(colonposition + 1) + newport + newurl.Mid(slashposition) ;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
CString oldurl = L"https://abc.com:8140/abc/bcd";    
CString newurl ;
Replace(oldurl, newurl, L"6143") ;
// now newurl contains the transformed URL
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem is [regular expressions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/).

Comment: No, the easiest solution is to loop through the character array. Regular expressions are ugly, slower and require an extra skillset  but they result to smaller code.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the string for tokens : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

C++11 or Boost provide regular expression support.
In your case 2 simple expression should be sufficient:

1. ^https?:// to match with the protocol,
2. :\d{1,5}/ to match with the port number

Just developed and tested those 2 regex using http://www.regextester.com/

Now if you look at the code below, we declare the 2 regex and use the regex_replace function coming with the C++11 STL.

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::string input ("https://abc.com:8140/abc/bcd");
    std::string output_reference ("http://abc.com:6143/abc/bcd");

     std::regex re_protocol ("^https?://");  //https to http
     std::regex re_port(":\\d{1,5}/"); //port number replacement, NB note that we use \\d.

     std::string result = std::regex_replace(std::regex_replace (input, re_protocol, "http://"), re_port, ":6143/");

     if(output_reference != result) {
         std::cout << "error." << std::endl;
         return -1; 
     }
     std::cout << input << " ==> " <<   result << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
https://abc.com:8140/abc/bcd ==> http://abc.com:6143/abc/bcd
```

Note that as the new STL take a large inspiration in Boost, you can adapt that C++11 code to the old C++ just by using `boost::regex` instead of `std::regex`.

```
#include "boost/regex.hpp"

boost::regex re_protocol ("^https?://");  //https to http
boost::regex re_port(":\\d{1,5}/"); //port number replacement, NB note that we use \\d.      
std::string result = boost::regex_replace(boost::regex_replace (input, re_protocol, "http://"), re_port, ":6143/");
```